# typescript that said has no exported member MyModule

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I just wrote an npm package with parcel + typescript + react.
https://github.com/Kamva/kamva-ui-kit

when I published it I faced to an error from typescript that said has no exported member 'Button'.
I can't figure out why this issue happening.

`import { Button} from "@kamva/ui-kit";`

Is there anyone have the same problem or help me?

Comment: https://github.com/Kamva/kamva-ui-kit/blob/master/index.d.ts - it looks like it's not exported indeed

Comment: @zerkms index.d.ts is no problem, look at src/index.tsx

Comment: Not sure how `src/index.tsx` is relevant since you're not importing it do you?

Comment: @zerkms when I run **npm run build**, parcel build src/index.tsx file and make the dist/index.js its file that is main file for npm package

Comment: That's correct. And your `index.d.ts` does not have the corresponding typing. How do you think `tsc` is supposed to find types from the `dist/index.js` if you did not export them explicitly in the `index.d.ts`? Import the original typescript files, or put your types in `index.d.ts`.

Comment: thanks@zerkms. yup seems I used the index.d.ts file in the wrong way.